# HTML5 Server-Sent Events: How to set withCredentials option?

Tags: javascript, html, server-sent-events

According to [WHATWG - Server-Sent Events](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#eventsource) below is the API for using **EventSource** interface:

```
[Constructor(DOMString url, optional EventSourceInit eventSourceInitDict)]
interface EventSource : EventTarget {
  readonly attribute DOMString url;
  readonly attribute boolean withCredentials;
  //....
};
```

> The withCredentials attribute must return the value to which it was
>   last initialized. When the object is created, it must be initialized
>   to false.

Simple example:

```
var stocks = new EventSource("events.php");
stocks.onmessage = function (event) {
  //alert(event.data);
};
```

#### Now, how to include or set withCredentials in this example?

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with the final code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've  not tried it, but going by the spec you link to, I believe it would be like this:

```
var stocks = new EventSource("events.php", { withCredentials: true });
```

If you go to http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-exceptions then scroll up to see the example  immediately above that, you can see a similar pattern of using a dictionary to set initialization values.

Comment: Its correct, I tried many syntax but Firebug not triggered any error with this :)

Comment: I Googled this pattern, I found also [w3c -> event-source -> eventsource-cross-origin.htm](https://github.com/w3c/event-source/blob/master/eventsource-cross-origin.htm) Using same concept

Comment: @user1646111 -- dead link; the new one is here: http://w3c-test.org/eventsource/eventsource-cross-origin.htm

Comment: Adding the `, { withCredentials: true }` solved my problem