# How to handle stream in Angular HTTPClient

Tags: angular, stream, httpclient, chunks

I have a backend (Spring Boot) API that writes data chunks to the response. I am trying to read that from my Angular code. What I expected was to receive chunks of data from the server. However the `get` method of `httpClient` does not return anything till all the data is retrieved from the server. I have given the code below

### Spring Boot code

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> fetchData(@RequestParam String path) {
    try {
        Pair<InputStream, Long> streamAndLen = CommonUtils.getTestStream();
        InputStream stream = streamAndLen.getKey();
        StreamingResponseBody resp =  outputStream -> {
            CommonUtils.copy(stream, outputStream);
            stream.close();
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
            .contentLength(streamAndLen.getValue())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(resp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get the data for the requested file", e);
    }
}

==============CommonUtils==================

public static Pair<InputStream, Long> getTestStream() {
    File file = new File("file_path_in_system");
    try {
        return new Pair<>(new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " is not found.", e);
    }
}

public static void copy(InputStream stream, OutputStream outputStream) {
    try {
        int buffSize = 1024 * 4;
        byte[] data = new byte[buffSize];
        int length = -1;
        while ((length = stream.read(data)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(data, 0, length);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `Pair` is just a key and value POJO.

### Angular snippet

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
this.http.get(env.streamURL + '?path=' + this.filePath, { headers, observe: 'body', reportProgress: true, responseType: 'blob' })
  .pipe(
    map(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (res: any) => {
      console.log('res = ' + res);
    }
  );
```

I want to get chunks of data (After every call to `flush` from the server) in my Angular application rather than waiting for all the chunks. Is there a way it can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get chunks from the server, I will suggest HTML 5 API, i.e. SSE

You can read more about it 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Also, you can see the demo in the below link 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am looking at something where I can pass the auth credentials or tokens. When I tried using SSE earlier, I figured out that EventSource doesnt support authentication.

Comment: You can pass an EventSourceInit object to the EventSource constructor, e.g. `new EventSource(url, { withCredentials: true })`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266493/html5-server-sent-events-how-to-set-withcredentials-option

Comment: Using SSE is a bad idea because browsers restrict them up to max connections around 5